# How to make a Custom Permission django-rest

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, permissions

im new at django-rest, so im trying to create a permission for employees to only GET or PUT their infos ,i used has_object_permission but i still can access to all other users

permissions.py:

```
class IsHRadmin(BasePermission):
    message = 'You are not allowed'
    def has_permission(self,request,view):

        methods = ['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE']
        req = request.user
        user = Role_User.objects.get(user_id_id=req.id)
   
        role ="HR_Admin"

        if str(user.role_id)==role:
            print("Hello World")
            if request.method in methods:
                return True    
        return False

class IsEmployee(BasePermission):
    message = 'You are not allowed'
    def has_object_permission(self,request,view,obj):
        
        methods = ['GET','PUT']
        
        if request.method in methods:
            if obj.owner == request.user:
                return True 
        return False
```

views.py:

```
class EmployeeDetail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                    generics.GenericAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer

    auth1 = IsAuthenticated & IsEmployee
    auth2 = IsAuthenticated & IsHRadmin
    
    permission_classes = [auth1 | auth2 | IsAdminUser]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return employee.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        response = self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
       
        return response

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not working with an admin (or hr admin user)?

Comment: sorry ,i didnt understand your question

Comment: with what type of user did you *test* the view?

Comment: a user with employee role

Comment: and that user is not a HR admin? Can you share the `IsHRAdmin` permission?

Comment: no he is not ,only one role accepted

Comment: can you [edit] the question (and thus copy an indented version)? It looks like your `IsHRadmin` also accepts non-hr users.

Comment: couldnt edit the question cuz it contain alot of code

Comment: can you then use pastebin for example? https://pastebin.com/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4A7JStGN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `IsHRadmin` has view level permission checking `has_permission` defined and not object-level permission checking `has_object_permission`. Now. by default, `has_object_permission` returns True, so while other permissions allow the user to access the view, the `IsHRadmin` allows him to access the object, even when he shouldn't. So you should define an object level permission in `IsHRadmin`

```
def has_object_permission(self,request,view, obj):
    return self.has_permission(request, view)
```